# DAO stop inserting to database after certain times

Tags: android, database, dao, android-room

I run into this weird problem, The gist is when I click on a movie I will insert the data into my local database using Android-room and Dao. However, inserting only work certain times (sometimes one sometimes up to eight), after that no matter how many times I click on the movie(different movie), it will no longer insert into the database. I have no error in my program, and I tried to debug it, inserting gets run every time when I click but new data is jus t no longer showing up in the database.

Here is my code for Dao which is pretty standard.

```
@Dao
public interface MovieDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY title")
    LiveData<List<MovieEntry>> loadAllTasks();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertTask(MovieEntry taskEntry);

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void updateTask(MovieEntry movieEntry);

    @Query("DELETE FROM movie where title= :title")
    void deleteTask(String title);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id = :id")
    LiveData<MovieEntry> loadMovieById(int id);

    @Query("DELETE FROM movie")
    void deleteALL();
}
```

And here is my code that gets run everytime movie gets click

```
     appExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            movieDatabase.movieDao().insertTask(movie_obj);
            LogUtil.d(LOG_TAG,"INSERTING INTO DATABASE");
        }
    });
```

Everything is pretty standard and there is no error... 
I am using Android Debug Database to check the updates on My database .

---

Here is my Entity Implementation I have all the setters and getterrs 
but it would be waste of space to show it here

```
   @Entity(tableName = "movie")
    public class MovieEntry {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        private int id;
        private String title;
        private String posterURL;
        private String topRate;
        private String popularity;
        private String language;
        private Boolean favorite;
        private String releaseDate;
        private String overview;
        private String sortBy;

    //This constructor writes to the database, so it does not know what the id would be
        @Ignore
        public MovieEntry(String title, String posterURL, String topRate, 
        String popularity, String language, Boolean favorite, String 
        releaseDate, String overview,String sortBy) {
            this.title = title;
            this.posterURL = posterURL;
            this.topRate = topRate;
            this.popularity = popularity;
            this.language = language;
            this.favorite = favorite;
            this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
            this.overview = overview;
            this.sortBy=sortBy;
           }
  // when read from the database then id would be required
        public MovieEntry(int id,String title, String posterURL, String 
         topRate, String popularity, String language, Boolean favorite, 
         String releaseDate, String overview,String sortBy) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.posterURL = posterURL;
            this.topRate = topRate;
            this.popularity = popularity;
            this.language = language;
            this.favorite = favorite;
            this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
            this.overview = overview;
            this.sortBy=sortBy;

        }
```

Comment: Can you share your entity implementation?

Comment: Hi I have shared the entity implementation as you requested

Comment: IDK if this will fix it, but I suspect that you're inserting data with the same ID, try to change the annotation of the DAO's insert method to `OnConflictStrategy.FAIL` and see if a `SQLiteConstraintException` gets fired.

Comment: yea, unfortunately, it did not help